# How can I config my git for pushing?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Every time, when I want to push, I use this command:

```
$ git push
```

And it throws this error:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

And the error will be gone when I use this command:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Ok, I can always use this ^ command, but I want to knon, can I say to git, *{when I say `push`, I mean `push origin master`}* once forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you give your local branch an upstream

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

then after that, the following will "just work"

```
git push
```

You only have to do the first command if the remote branch does not already exist.

To check if you are already tracking a remote branch you can type

```
git branch -vv
```

Then it will list something like

```
master    abcd123 [origin/master] Some commit message
```

Then you can see that your local `master` branch is tracking the remote `origin/master` branch.

Comment: How can I understand "does the remote branch exist or not" ?

Answer (score 1):

or you can use short version of this notation:

```
git push --set-upstream origin <REMOTE_NAME>

git push -u origin <REMOTE_NAME>
```

git needs to know which remote branch you are trying to push your code to.